# '$x' is undefined, while verify the Xpath in IE11 console for webdriver

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xpath, console, webdriver

Automating the organization web application using selenium webdriver and it supports only in IE browser. While verifying the Xpath in IE11 browser console I am getting the error as `'$x' is undefined`.

Xpath: `//a[@id='gb_70']`

Link: https://www.google.co.in - > Sign In button

Verified Xpath in IE11 console: `$x("//a[@id='gb_70']")`

Error: `'$x' is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not now have, and has never had, a native XPath-over-HTML-DOM engine. As such, it’s highly unsurprising that the dev tools `$x()` shortcut won’t work in the IE developer tools. Any XPath processing done by Selenium in IE is done using a JavaScript XPath engine. You can attempt to load such a library and use `document.evaluate` with it to process the page DOM using XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `document.evaluate` method to test the xpath in IE.

```
// evaluate the xpath and get the matching nodes (similar to selenium findelements())
elements = document.evaluate("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
// to get the number of items matched (similar to selenium findelements().size())
elements.snapshotLength
// get the first element node (similar to selenium findelements().get(0))
elements.snapshotItem(0)
```

The `elements.snapshotLength` will be `0` if there are no element nodes matching with the given xpath. It will be `>2` if more than one element matched the xpath.

[image]

Here is the link to get more information on [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) method.

Comment: I've verified the xpath  with document.evaluate method but I am getting the another error as 'XPathResult' is undefined. Check this link for reference [link](https://imgur.com/jALjMBl)

Comment: what's your browser IE version?